Does cocoapods support pods directly referencing each other's header files by default?
i have a demo project testPod ,after runs bundle exec pod install,the pods have been correctly installed.
there are two pods names AFNetworking and YYKit

the Podfile content are:
target 'testPod' do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'YYKit'
end

I can sure AFNetworking does not dependency YYKit, ant AFNetworking header search path not include YYKit.
But AFNetworking can indeed include YYKit header file.
enter image description here
enter image description here
CocoaPods Environment
CocoaPods: 1.10.1
Xcode: 15.4
So I'm curious, why can pod AFNetworking import another pod's header file here?
